# A small suggestion to be considered before sharing personal info

Tags: discussion, suggestions

Though we have a great platform to discuss Hinduism and also able to chat. Sometimes some users want to get in personal touch with other users by sharing personal emails, which is completely fine.

But in comparison to other SE sites, religious sites are [strongly bound with individual faiths](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2158/93). Some people respectfully have aggressive agenda to convert/involve others in their agenda - either that could be in favor or against one's faith. Some people start to hate you once they know your faith. Or even if everything aligns, one might find in a frequent disturbing state when being in contact with them.

This is just a general urge post not to share your personal contacts with any user until you really know that user. Give preference to sharing proxy or dummy mail or other contacts but not the personal info by which one can track that user. Unfortunately, I did this with a maniac and that person kept on sharing hatred, threatening emails with me, and also even marked my email with other well-known organizations so that they can act against me - This all was going on for more than a month. Hopefully, everything is stopped now. Blocking such emails won't be enough as they keep on going against you with other organizations.

TBH, I shared my email with many individuals on Stackoverflow (programming) but never had such a situation before. Which made me realized programming doesn't run on faith as religious sites do. There are actively many such users on this site who are collecting personal emails to be successful in whatever agenda they have. Be cautious.

Comment: Hindu student? :D :D

Comment: Can u pls make title more specific.. something like "A small suggestion to be considered before sharing personal info"..by title I thought u r collecting personal info :D

Comment: If you are starting to receive "threatening emails" that is indeed serious.

Comment: @YDS lol done..

Comment: :-O  ....... ....

Comment: Thanks @Mr_Green.......

Comment: @Archit - that HinduStudent lady is definitely a pain to deal with