# Can this answer be made objective, clearly marking sectarian views as sectarian?

Tags: support

[When Devi Bhagavatam says Gods as doers of karma and that they are sinners, how they can remove my sin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42945/when-devi-bhagavatam-says-gods-as-doers-of-karma-and-that-they-are-sinners-how)

> However, Shiva and Brahma are still under the influence of karma, since they are created by Narayana, as declared in the Narayana Upanishad:

This is cherry-picking scriptural citations.

Svetasvatara Upanishad says otherwise.

Then we go to level II - whenever a scripture says God X is Brahman - "X" is a name of Vishnu or Vishnu is the Antaryami of X.  This entire edifice rests on the deity-name "Narayana" and it has been proven at this site that Panini does not support the views of this sect about "Narayana" and that other gods are also called Narayana and equated to Brahman.

Obviously, only some Hindus are going to accept this.

> Moreover, the Devi Bhagavatam is regarded as a Tamasic Purana, since it contradicts the supremacy of Sattvic Lord Vishnu, who is declared by the Vedas to be the supreme Brahman.

This site has discussed the "Tamasic Purana" thingy ad infinitum - it is in the eye of the beholder.

At least in the Rig Veda Vishnu has a birth and is subordinate to Indra.

Citations of Ramanuja are of importance only to his followers.

> However, only Lord Vishnu can grant moksha, since he is the supreme Lord and beyond all sins:

Directly contradicted by Rig Veda "tryambakam Yajamahe" and Mahabharata (krishna himself says Siva grants Moksha).

This answer is presenting the views of one sect as the views of Hinduism, views that are hurtful to non-followers of the sect.

I don't want to enter into an argument with the poster of this answer - just asking him to add a caveat that he is presenting the views of his sect.

Comment: I would say.. Ignore it! If the answer is in scope but against one's belief better to ignore it. No need to request the user to keep any disclaimer that it is based on a sect related. Upvote the other answer with which you agree or post your answer. [Check my previous similar post here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2158/93)

Comment: It is not an answer.  A question is asked based on Devi Bhagavatam and the answer basically says what Devi Bhagavtam says is all lies.  But HSE doesn't want to solve this problem @mr_Green

Comment: Oh, I get it now. That shouldn't how the answer should be. my bad.

Comment: On second thought, I think it is still fine. I agree with [this comment here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42945/when-devi-bhagavatam-says-gods-as-doers-of-karma-and-that-they-are-sinners-how#comment133034_42956). But let's see what others have to say.

Comment: An argument is based on Devi Bhagavatam and the answer says it is a "Tamasa purana."  Why don't you ask the user who posted this "rebuttal" to ignore what the original poster wrote based on Devi Bhagavatam?  He could have written one line - "not all Hindus accept everything in Devi Bhagavatam" - instead he writes things that Zakir Naik could write - except that it is sect-based denigration instead of againt all of Hinduism @mr_green